# Redirect to ClickOnce .application file requires site to be in a zone with Medium-Low security

Tags: security, internet-explorer, redirect, clickonce

We have a page that conditionally redirects to a clickonce .application file. All of a sudden the redirect stopped happening. Tested the following:
- Redirect works fine in Chrome (of course Chrome can't open a ClickOnce file)
- Redirect works fine if using localhost build
- Redirect works fine when putting the site in Intranet or Trusted Sites and setting security to Medium Low (default appears to be Medium)

Using the IE settings UI and starting with Medium security and customizing, even when setting all options to Enable, the clickonce application was not being redirected to. As soon as the setting was set to Medium Low, it started work. So it appears that a setting not exposed in the UI is affecting this.

The clickonce application launches fine when launched from a link on a web page.

The problem only occurs when the URL is changed via document.location.href.

Was there a security update, IE update, or something else that would have affected this behavior?

Comment: This happens for me too. I had to add the site in 'Trusted Sites' and reduce the Security level from Medium to Medium Low. Only then it worked. 
I am still unclear on why this security setting is required to be changed in order for this to work.